# Azure + Socket IO produces Error 404

Tags: node.js, azure, socket.io

NodeJS and socket.io seems to work fine but inspecting the logs I can see an "HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found" error that I cannot identify why is happening. For example my full url where nodejs is hosted is sample-nodejs.azurewebsites.net 
and I get the following error:

[image: error 404]

**Update with more information:**

I tried different combinations of setting up the server (using or not express) but I always get the same result.
I initialize my server like this:

```
var http = require('http');
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 1337;
var server = http.createServer();
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
server.listen(PORT);

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket)
{
   ...
});
```

I used socket.io 1.7.4 through the current latest 2.0.3. and I get the same issue. Debugging the client seems fine but inspecting the Errors from azure "Log stream" I can see randomly (didn't realize a pattern) HTTP 404.0 - Not Found errors and is requesting a url from https://sample-nodejs:80/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&a..

Isn't the url strange since the full path for the server is sample-nodejs.azurewebsites.net ?

Comment: Did you mean the socket.io works fine on Azure Web Apps, but you still get the 404 error? Could you provide more info, like the code snippet and your project stucture?

Comment: Seeing the same thing. Exactly.

Comment: up! here same error 404 =/